# Insertando imagen mientras se carga una actividad en Android

Tags: android

En mi app tengo la clase `WebViewActivity` que demora en cargarse y para `evitar una pantalla vacía` estoy tratando de insertar una imagen usando `ImageView` para que se visualiza solo durante 5 segundo hasta que se cargue la `WebViewActivity`, pero tengo `error` en `context`, alguien me podria decir como resolver esto.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
ublic class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button button;
private ImageView mImage;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    startCountDownTimer();
//        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
//        startActivity(intent);
}

private void startCountDownTimer() {
    new CountDownTimer( 5000, 5000 ) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //finish();
        }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Aquí el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes inicializar `context`después de `super.onCreate...`

```
private Context context;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    startCountDownTimer();
//        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
//        startActivity(intent);
}
```